# Basic question on Dehn twists

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

Let $\Sigma$ be a topological surface (compact and orientable, if necessary). Let $C$ be a subspace of $\Sigma$ homeomorphic to the annulus $A := [0,1] \times S^1$, together with a homeomorphism $h: A \to C$. We define the **Dehn twist** supported on $C$ to be the homeomorphism $T_C: \Sigma \to \Sigma$ defined by $T_C(p) = h \circ \tau \circ h^{-1}(p)$ if $p \in C$, and $T_C(p) = p$ otherwise. Here, the map $\tau: A \to A$ is defined as $\tau(r,\theta) = (r,\theta e^{2 \pi i r})$.

In turn, we define the **characteristic loop** of $C$ to be the map $\gamma_C: S^1 \to \Sigma$ given by $\gamma_C(\theta)=h(0,\theta)$.

I would like to show the following basic result:

> Given two annuli $C_0$ and $C_1$ of $\Sigma$ as above, $T_{C_0}$ and $T_{C_1}$ are isotopic if and only if $\gamma_{C_0}$ and $\gamma_{C_1}$ are isotopic.

However, I was unable to give a proof, and in fact, I think the result relies on nontrivial topological fact. For instance, to prove the sufficient condition I would argue as follows. Let $g_t$ be an isotopy from $T_{C_0}$ to $T_{C_1}$. Let $C_t$ be the support of $g_t$. If each $C_t$ was homeomorphic to $A$, and moreover, such homeomorphisms could be chosen to be continuous in $t$, then we would be done, since we would have a map

$$\tilde{g}: I \times A \to \Sigma,$$

and restricting to $r=0$ would give us the desired isotopy between $\gamma_{C_0}$ and $\gamma_{C_1}$. However, I think that claim is highly nontrivial.

I also checked the book *A Prior on Mapping Class Groups*, by Farb and Margalit, but their argument is not elaborated.

In summary, I would like a reference or a proof of the result mentioned above.

Thank you in advance for reading!

Comment: @LeeMosher Hi, the question is the second to last line, i.e. to prove the claim in the box. The discussion about the proof of the sufficient condition is just to highlight that the result is probably based on a nontrivial topological fact. In any case, it's not true that $C_t = g_t(C_0)$: for example if $C_0$ and $C_1$ are disjoint, then $g_1(C_0) = C_0 \neq C_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of the sufficient condition.

For each homeomorphism $f : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ and each nontrivial simple closed curve $\gamma \subset \Sigma$ one may ask whether $f(\gamma)$ is isotopic to $\gamma$. In other words, one may ask whether the isotopy class of $\gamma$, which I'll denote $[\gamma]$, is fixed by $f$. Let me use $Fix(f)$ to denote the set of all such $[\gamma]$ that are fixed by $f$.

Next, one shows that if $f,g : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ are isotopic homeomorphisms then $Fix(f) = Fix(g)$.

Next, one shows that for any annulus $C \subset \Sigma$, the set $Fix(T_C)$ consists of those $[\gamma]$ such that the minimal geometric intersection number of the core curve of $C$ with curves in the class $[\gamma]$, a number that I will denote $i(C,\gamma)$, is equal to zero.

Next, one shows that $C$ is an inessential annulus (one that is isotopic to an annulus contained in a disc) if and only if $T_C$ is isotopic to the identity if and only if $T_C$ fixes every $[\gamma]$.

Finally, and here is the heart of the matter: one shows that if $C_0,C_1$ are two inessential annuli and if $C_0$ is not isotopic to $C_1$ then there exists a nontrivial simple closed curve $\gamma$ such that $i(C_0,\gamma)=0$ and $i(C_1,\gamma)>0$. This is best done using a case analysis. First one isotopes $C_0,C_1$ so that they are in efficient position, meaning that their core curves have minimal geometric intersection number; denote that number by $i(C_0,C_1)$. Now one breaks into cases.

Let me start with the case that $i(C_0,C_1)=0$; up to isotopy this is equivalent to saying that $C_0,C_1$ are disjoint. Since $C_0$, $C_1$ are essential, no component of $S-C_0$ nor of $S-C_1$ is a disc. Since we have assumed the cores of $C_0$ and $C_1$ are not isotopic, no component of $\Sigma - (C_0 \cup C_1)$ is an annulus. Let $\Sigma' \subset \Sigma$ be the component of $\Sigma - C_0$ that contains $C_1$. One can construct $\gamma$ so that $\gamma \subset \Sigma'$ and hence $i(C_0,\gamma)=0$, and so that one of the following subcases holds: $C_1$ does not separate $\Sigma'$ and $i(C_1,\gamma')=1$; or $C_1$ does separate $\Sigma'$ and $i(C_1,\gamma')=2$.

In the other case that $i(C_0,C_1) > 0$, one starts by picking $\Sigma'$ to be any component of $S-C_0$. In this case the core curve of $C_1$ intersects $\Sigma'$ in an arc system, meaning a pairwise disoint system of properly embedded arcs, each of which is essential (i.e. not homotopic rel endoints into the boundary of $\Sigma'$). The argument now comes down to showing that for any essential arc system in $\Sigma'$ there exists an essential curve $\gamma$ in $\Sigma'$ which intersects that arc system essentially in at least one point. If any single one of these arcs is nonseparating then we can simply choose $\gamma$ to cross that arc in a single point. If all of those arcs are separating, then one can choose $\gamma$ to intersect that arc essentially in two points.